# MS SQL Server - How to delete and read Transaction log file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, logging, transactions

Could someone please help with deleting(shrink and delete) and if possible reading a Transaction log files on SQL Server management studio. (in flex environment.)

Thank you.

Comment: Shrinking - google various ways to shrink databases or just the transaction log. Delete transaction log while keeping the database? Not possible. As for reading the raw log, don't. Why don't you tell us what issue(s) you're trying to solve with this question and we may be able to help a lot more.

Comment: You can read the transaction log with the undocumented `fn_dblog()` T-SQL table-valued function. Use `DBCC_SHRINKFILE` to reduce size, but don't do that routinely. Don't delete the log file as it a critical part of your database. If you are having problems managing the log size, add details to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It was because of security of the transaction operations that we did. It would be great if i could know where the physical transaction log file is located ?